# Get defaultGroupId of firefox.exe in Win7

Tags: windows-7, process, firefox-addon, profile, xpcom

I was trying to separate the group of windows per profile in Win7. I found out this is doable by creating a preference in ALL profiles of `taskbar.grouping.useprofile` and setting it to true and restarting browser of all profiles (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=644914).

But how it works is it changes the defaultGroupId `Cc["@mozilla.org/windows-taskbar;1"].getService(Ci.nsIWinTaskbar).defaultGroupId`

The problem with this is before this prefernce is created the Firefox uses the `defaultGroupId` of the firefox.exe BUT after creating the pref profiles now have a defaultGroupId different from that. SO if initially, before creating that pref and restarting browsers, if user had `firefox.exe` pinned then it will always be separate after the pref is created and browsers restarted.

So what I want to do is for the profile marked as `Default=1` in profiles.ini I want to programatically make it use the `defaultGroupId` of the `firefox.exe` but the thing is once pref is created and browser restarted I can't figure out the `defaultGroupId` of the `firefox.exe`.

My last resort solution is: (1) On install of my addon if the pref of `taskbar.grouping.useprofile` *is* there and set to true, then set it to false and ask user to restart then on restart it will figure out the `defaultGrupId` and store it as a preference then I will add the pref back then ask user to restart again (really dont want to do this) (2) On install of my addon if if the pref of `taskbar.grouping.useprofile` is *not* there and set to true then just set the preference to the value of the current `defaultGroupId`.

Comment: I'm thinking this is possible. Is it possible to read `wt.defaultGroupId` before this code here runs: http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/widget/windows/WinTaskbar.cpp#252

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Neil for letting me know that the default group id can be found in the registry, even after setting the preference of `taskbar.grouping.useprofile` to `true`.

[ask.m.o :: How to calculate default group id (Win7+)](https://ask.mozilla.org/question/1012/how-to-calculate-default-group-id-win7/?answer=1060#post-id-1060)

Solution from ask.m.o:

> Thanks @Neil I got the value this way. The only possible problem I run
>   into, is what if there is more than one value under TaskBarIDs, is
>   this possible?
>
> I also might run into problem if value type is of `0` which is
>   `TYPE_NONE` or `REG_NONE` is it possible to read these values?
>
> ```
> var wrk = Cc['@mozilla.org/windows-registry-key;1'].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowsRegKey);
> var keypath = 'Software\\Mozilla\\' + Services.appinfo.name + '\\TaskBarIDs'; //Services.appinfo.name == appInfo->GetName(appName) // http://mxr.mozilla.org/comm-central/source/mozilla/widget/windows/WinTaskbar.cpp#284
> try {
>   wrk.open(wrk.ROOT_KEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, keypath, wrk.ACCESS_READ);
> } catch(ex) {
>   //console.warn(ex)
>   if (ex.message != 'Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIWindowsRegKey.open]') {
>     throw ex;
>   } else {
>     try {
>       wrk.open(wrk.ROOT_KEY_CURRENT_USER, keypath, wrk.ACCESS_READ);
>     } catch (ex) {
>       throw ex;
>     }
>   }
> }
> //list children
> var numVals = wrk.valueCount;
> for (var i=0; i<numVals; i++) {
>   var keyval = {
>     Name: wrk.getValueName(i)
>   };
>   keyval.Type = wrk.getValueType(keyval.Name);
>   keyval.TypeStr = win_RegTypeStr_from_RegTypeInt(keyval.Type);
>   if (keyval.Type == 0) {
>     throw new Error('keyval.Type is `0` I have no idea how to read this value keyval.Type == `' + keyval.Type + '` and keyval. Name == `' + keyval.Name + '`');    
>   }
>   keyval.Value = wrk['read' + keyval.TypeStr + 'Value'](keyval.Name)
>   console.log('keyval:', uneval(keyval), keyval);
> }
> wrk.close();
> function win_RegTypeStr_from_RegTypeInt(int) {
>   if (int == 1) {
>     return 'String';
>   } else if (int == 3) {
>     return 'Binary';
>   } else if (int == 4) {
>     return 'Int';
>   } else if (int == 11) {
>     return 'Int64';
>   } else if (int == 0) {
>     return 'NONE';
>   } else {
>     throw new Error('keyval.Type is not any of the expected values of 0, 2, 3, 4, or 11 so am now confused. keyval.Type == `' + int + '`');
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> [image]
>
> [image]